# How to render frames skipping every X , but leaving the filename increment by one

Tags: rendering, animation

I know how to skip frames in blender, but it seems the filename follows the skipped frames.  So if I want to render very 10 frames starting at 0 and finishing at 50.  I would like to see this

image0.png
iamge1.png
image2.png
image3.png
image4.png
image5.png

but this is what I get

image0.png
iamge10.png
image20.png
image30.png
image40.png
image50.png

Comment: Could you scale that location of your keyframes down by a factor of 10, and just render every frame?

Comment: Maybe you could render using a python script that advances the current frame in the scene by the desired stepsize using a for loop. Then in every iteration it sets the name of the output file using `bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = <path_with_correct_framenumber>.png` and then calls `bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment from @maddin45 I wrote this simple python script:

```
import bpy

def render_range(start, stop, step):
    # First make sure that are values are all ints and not floats.
    start = int(start)
    stop = int(stop)
    step = int(step)

    filepath = bpy.context.scene.render.filepath

    for frame in range(start, stop, step):
        bpy.context.scene.frame_current = frame

        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = filepath + '%04d' % (frame / step)

        bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )

    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = filepath

if __name__ = '__main__':
    render_range(0, 60, 10)
```

So basically this will loop through every 10'th frame starting at 0 and ending at 60(note that it does not include 60, but rather ends just before it).

To make it render another range(such as every 5'th frame starting at 10 and ending at 100) then change the last line from:

```
    render_range(0, 60, 10)
```

To:

```
    render_range(10, 105, 5) # Note that we add our step amount to our desired stopping point so that it will end at 100 instead of 95.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the 'Time remapping' slider to quickly adjust the global timing of the animation.

If you want to render every 10 frames, set the New time to 10 (100/10), and also set the end frame to 1/10th of the actual length.

[image]